# In yii why we don't use action static

Tags: php, yii, yii2

When we create an action in controller then why we don't use it static

```
Public static function actionLogin(){
}
```

Comment: Could that the question is why we should use static function for action ??

Answer (score 1):

```
$this
```

The whole application get the `$this` from controller classes, so we cannot use the static keyword.

Answer (score 0):

Because the controller is being instantiated and the actions might access properties of the controller.